# MutationObserver - how to detect dom changes within iframe

Tags: javascript

Let me first explain the problem:
My script has a mutationobserver, which detects added nodes, and does some processing on the content - like compare and highlight some values.
The current implementation detects changes in the entire document body, the target looks like this

```
var target = document.querySelector('body');
```

Everything works well, except when there is an iframe.
Some client pages have an iframe or multiple iframes, others do not.

My script is added within a script tag in the parent document.

Question:
a) is it possible to get the same MutationObserver to detect changes in body and iframe ? ie everything in the dom including the iframe
b) if it is not possible with a single observer, what is the alternate method?

please note: my script can only go to the main/parent document

Comment: If you don't own the domain of the iframe, or the iframe doesn't give you access to it's dom (`document.domain = '...'`) then you cannot

Comment: what if the iframe domain is from the same domain as that of client?

Comment: it should work then as long as you are grabbing the iframe properly... `document.getElementByTagName('iframe').document.body`

Comment: can you be a little more specific? you mean I should have a second mutationobserver, with target as document.getElementByTagName('iframe').document.body  ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You will need to have a different mutationobserver for each iframe that you want to watch. So if you want one on the current document you will also need a different observer there as well.

If you have access to the iframe, you can then watch it like so:

```
// Get the iframe body
let iframe = document.getElementById('my-iframe').document.body
// Setup the config
let config = { attributes: true, childList: true }
// Create a callback
let callback = function(mutationsList) { /* callback actions */ }

// Watch the iframe for changes
let observer = new MutationObserver(callback)
observer.observe(iframe, config)
```

If the iframe is on a sub-domain of the parent you can use this in the iframe:

```
// where parent.com is the parent domain of the iframe
document.domain = 'parent.com'
```

**Note:** `document.domain` is now deprecated.

If you do not own the domain of the iframe you're out of luck.

Comment: I was trying this out. however, the iframe document object is null. the "baseURI" property of iframe shows the same domain as the parent. what could be going wrong?

Comment: Make sure `document.domain` is the same in the iframe and the parent. That is the property that needs to validate the same

Comment: Didn't work / was unreliable for me until I changed the `iframe` to be `document.getElementById('my-iframe').contentWindow.document.body` and added `subtree:true` to the `config` variables.

Comment: Also note that this works if you are increasing the body in size, but not when you are decreasing it (at least in chrome) - it instead remains at the maximum height. A good solution is to use a wrapper around the content and then `getBoundingClientRect().height` to get the wrapper's height